# JavaScript ChildNodes Undefined type error?

Tags: javascript, types, undefined, child-nodes

Hello I am new to coding and have a generic question, I looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution. I was following a javascript tutorial and came across this particular line of code. The childnode states that the property 'backgroundColor' is undefined and I am not sure why.

error : "Uncaught typeerror: cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>


 <div id = "sampDiv">

  <p> This is a txt field </p>

  <p> This is another txt field </p>

  </div>



  <script>

  var sampDiv = document.getElementById("sampDiv");

  sampDiv.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the exact error message into your question.

Comment: The problem is `childNodes` includes the text nodes representing the whitespace between `<div id="sampDiv">` and `<p>`. Text nodes do not have `style` properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `children[0]` instead of `childNodes[0]`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

```js
  var sampDiv = document.getElementById("sampDiv");

  sampDiv.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "sampDiv">
      <p> This is a txt field </p>
      <p> This is another txt field </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```